# Doctrine 2 - problems with "Getting Started XML-Edition" - generating database schema

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Having never touched Doctrine before (either 1 or 2), I am following [this tutorial for Doctrine 2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/cookbook/getting-started-xml-edition/en).

I'm at the point where I use the command line to generate the database schema. This is the cli-config.php file, as per the tutorial:

```
<?php
$cliConfig = new Doctrine\Common\Cli\Configuration();
$cliConfig->setAttribute('em', $entityManager);
```

When I run it though, I just get an error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Doctrine\Common\Cli\Configuration.php'
```

Because that class referenced by the cli-config.php file doesn't exist. I've also tried blanking the cli-config.php file, which of course doesn't work either - says that "The helper "em" is not defined."

I'm using version 2.0.0BETA3. I know that this is a beta version, so they could have changed some files around, but I can't find that class anywhere.

Any ideas on how to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs in the XML Getting Started are outdated in this regard. Please see the Tools section in the manual on how to configure the CLI Tool:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html

All the rest still works as described. I will update this part asap.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you installed Doctrine using **pear**

$ sudo pear install pear.doctrine-project.org/doctrineORM

which will install the three 'Doctrine 2' packages: DoctrineCommon, DoctrineDBAL, and DoctrineORM. On Ubuntu, these packages will be located in /usr/share/php/Doctrine, and the doctrine command line utility, will be installed into /usr/bin.

With this setup, this is a version of cli-config.php you can use (note: **DIR** should have two underscores before and after it. For some reason they didn't display).

```
<?php
require ‘Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php’;
// Setup Autoloader (1)
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::registerAutoloadPEAR();

require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$classLoader = new Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__); 

$classLoader->register();

$classLoader = new Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Proxies', __DIR__); 

$classLoader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

$config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache);

$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(__DIR__."/Entities"));

$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . '/Proxies');

$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

$connectionOptions = array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'dbname' => 'bugs',
        'user' => 'bugs',
        'password' => 'xyzabc',
  'host' => 'localhost' );

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));
```